# Replacing multiline batch file with a for loop which reads a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, psexec

I currently have a batch file that schedules chkdsk to run on multiple servers pending the next reboot-

```
c:\pstools\psexec \\server1 -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"  
c:\pstools\psexec \\server2 -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"  
c:\pstools\psexec \\server3 -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"  
c:\pstools\psexec \\server4 -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"  
c:\pstools\psexec \\server5 -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"
```

I am trying to understand how to construct a FOR loop which will read from a txt file composed of -

```
server1  
server2  
server3  
server4
```

The txt file will be located in the data folder on my local e: drive.  Also, is there any way to not have to enter the password for the user ID more than once?  Appreciate the guidance!  Thx and a Happy New Year to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a FOR, but you could also create a file named `servers.txt` that contains:

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
```

and run this command:

```
c:\pstools\psexec @servers.txt ...your command...
```

PsExec will execute the command on each of the computers listed in the file. Please see the [psexec documentation here](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), and see the `@file` parameter.

Comment: Thx for the tip!  So I assume the servers.txt will have to be in the same folder as psexec and the command would be -  c:\pstools\psexec @servers.txt -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"

Comment: @user275373 you can specify the full path `c:\pstools\psexec.exe @c:\servers.txt ...` for example...

Comment: Sorry.  Having trouble with responding.  Every time I hit return for a line break it saves the response prematurely!  So my command would be -  c:\pstools\psexec @e:\data\servers.txt -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F" ?  Is there a way to not have to type in the password for each server?  I'm using the same ID for all the following servers.  Thx again!

Comment: @user275373 you can specify it in the command line with the -p argument: `psexec -u username -p password cmd ....`

Comment: For security reasons we don't put it in a batch file so as to force the user who invokes it to enter it manually (also to keep it from being run by unauthorized users).  It would be nice to just have to enter it a single time rather than 100.

Comment: Update - I ran it, but only had to enter the pw once yet I did get errors that said "PsExec could not start cmd on server1:" followed by "Incorrect function." Then I got "couldn't access server2:"  I'll have to do further investigation.  At least it seems to be going thru the txt file so that's one step further!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a for loop method:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (servers.txt) do (
   c:\pstools\psexec \\%%a -d -u Domain\administrator cmd /c "echo Y | chkdsk c: /F"  
)
```

Comment: Thx.  I actually tried to use your answer for another problem but for some reason it only executes the first entry of the txt file.  I did for /f "delims=" %%a in (servers.txt) do (  
net use y: /delete
net use y: \\%%a\d$  
if exist "y:\Program Files\CA\Workload Automation AE\SystemAgent\%%a\cybagent.exe" goto STAGE  
echo Does not exist for %%a  
goto END  

:STAGE  
echo Exists for %%a  

:END  
net use y: /delete  
)

Comment: Tried to make it more readable, but the comments don't allow for linebreaks!

Comment: If you use a `goto` within a loop then it stops the loop completing, as it specifically branches to the label.   Instead of a `goto` use an `IF-ELSE` statement.